# Capturing a date from three different TextInput

Tags: react-native

I have three different TextInput, in each of one of them goes the day, month and year of birth.
How can I capture all three values and 'condense' them into a date when a button is pressed? Also, how can I validate that the numbers posted on the TextInputs are valid? (for example, the user can't put a 13 inside the month TextInput)

Here's my code:

```
class App extends Component { // AgeInput
state = { date: null, edad: null }

_ageCalc = (fecha) => {
  var hoy = new Date();
  var fechaNacimiento = new Date(fecha);
  var edad_ahora = hoy.getFullYear() - fechaNacimiento.getFullYear();
  var mes = hoy.getMonth() - fechaNacimiento.getMonth();

  if (mes < 0 || (mes === 0 && hoy.getDate() < fechaNacimiento.getDate())) {
    edad_ahora--;
  }

  this.setState({ edad: edad_ahora });
}

render () {
  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container} scrollEnabled enableOnAndroid={true} 
    resetScrollToCoords={{x:0, y:0}}>
      <View style={styles.topView}>
       <TouchableOpacity style={styles.img}>
         <Image source={flecha} />
       </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.topTextWrapper}>
       <Text style={styles.topTextPrimary}>Bienvenido a Neuron</Text>
         <Text style={styles.topTextSecondary}>¿O no?</Text>
       </View>
     </View>

     <View style={styles.middleView}>
      <Text style={styles.formText}>Fecha de nacimiento</Text>
      <View style={styles.formRow}>
        <View style={styles.textInputWrapper}>
          <TextInput style={styles.formInput} placeholder='DD' keyboardType='number-pad'/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.textInputWrapper}>
          <TextInput style={styles.formInput} placeholder='MM' keyboardType='number-pad'/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.textInputWrapper}>
          <TextInput style={styles.formInput} placeholder='AA' keyboardType='number-pad'/>
        </View>
      </View>                
    </View>

    <View style={styles.buttonView}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>CALCULAR EDAD</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.ageView}>
      <Text style={styles.ageTextPrimary}>Tu edad es:</Text>
      <Text style={styles.ageNumber}>{this.state.edad}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.ageTextSecondary}>Años</Text>
    </View>
  </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
);}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see below example. I think this will help you. Change this according to your requirement.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    date: '',
    month: '',
    year: '',
    isErrorDate: false,
    isErrorDateLenght: false,
    isErrorMonth: false,
    isErrorMonthLength: false,
    isErrorYear: false,
    isErrorYearLength: false
  };


  onChangeDate = value => {
    this.setState({
      date: value,
      isErrorDate: false,
      isErrorDateLenght: false,
    });
  };
  onChangeMonth = value => {
    this.setState({
      month: value,
      isErrorMonth: false,
      isErrorMonthLength: false,
    });
  };
  onChangeYear = value => {
    this.setState({
      year: value,
      isErrorYear: false,
      isErrorYearLength: false
    });
  };

  checkDate = () => {
    const { date, month, year } = this.state;
    let isErrorDate = date.trim() === '' ? true : false;
    let isErrorDateLenght = date.length > 2 || !/^[0-9]+$/.test(date) || date > 31 ? true : false;
    let isErrorMonth = month.trim() === '' ? true : false;
    let isErrorMonthLength = month.length > 2 || !/^[0-9]+$/.test(month) || month > 12 ? true : false;
    let isErrorYear = year.trim() === '' ? true : false;
    let isErrorYearLength = year.length > 4 || !/^[0-9]+$/.test(year) ? true : false;
    if (
      isErrorDate ||
      isErrorDateLenght ||
      isErrorMonth ||
      isErrorMonthLength ||
      isErrorYear ||
      isErrorYearLength
    ) {
      this.setState({
        isErrorDate: isErrorDate,
        isErrorDateLenght: isErrorDateLenght,
        isErrorMonth: isErrorMonth,
        isErrorMonthLength: isErrorMonthLength,
        isErrorYear: isErrorYear,
        isErrorYearLength: isErrorYearLength
      });
      Alert.alert('invalid date /month/ year')
    } else {
      //submit date
    }

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {/* <KeyboardAwareScrollView scrollEnabled enableOnAndroid={true}> */}
        <View >
          <TouchableOpacity >
            <Image />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View >
            <Text >Bienvenido a Neuron</Text>
            <Text >¿O no?</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View >
          <Text >Fecha de nacimiento</Text>
          <View >
            <View style={{ padding: 10 }} >
              <TextInput placeholder='DD' keyboardType='number-pad' value={this.state.date} onChangeText={this.onChangeDate} />
            </View>
            <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
              <TextInput placeholder='MM' keyboardType='number-pad' value={this.state.month} onChangeText={this.onChangeMonth} />
            </View>
            <View style={{ padding: 10 }} >
              <TextInput placeholder='AA' keyboardType='number-pad' value={this.state.year} onChangeText={this.onChangeYear} />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View >
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: 'gray', alignItems: 'center' }} onPress={this.checkDate}>
            <Text >CALCULAR EDAD</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <View >
          <Text >Tu edad es:</Text>
          <Text >Años</Text>
        </View>
        {/* </KeyboardAwareScrollView> */}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Feel free for doubts